# How to do a Regex Pattern in SQL Server for specific combination

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get codes that have certain combination of characters in a query in sql server.

Instead of saying in SQL Server

```
and TIL.code LIKE '%tf%' or code like 'fs%' or code like '%ls%'
```

Is there a single pattern I can use

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have Regex support, only basic pattern matching.

Comment: okay, if you/someone has a work around to avoid saying or.. so many times

Comment: 2 `OR`s isn't a lot in my opinion. Or are you saying you actually have (a lot) more than 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to avoid the `OR`s, rather than use Regex (which SQL Server doesn't support) you could use an `EXISTS`:

```sql
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM (VALUES('%tf'),('fs%'),('%ls%'))V(Pattern)
            WHERE TIL.Code LIKE V.Pattern)
```

If this is coming from a parameter, you would use a table type parameter, and then replace the `VALUES` table construct with that parameter:

```sql
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM @YourTableTypeParameter TTP
            WHERE TIL.Code LIKE TTP.YourPatternColumn)
```

Comment: helpful for something else I needed to accomplish. Thanks!